# To store all entries of a table (exceeding 6000 values) in 3 arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to store the values of a table (3 columns) in 3 different arrays each containing the information of 1 column. There are more than 6000 entries. But I get an error :

> "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test_array.php on line 17"

What should I do?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: At the very least - add your code to the question. The table definition might also be helpful.

Comment: I want to perform some computations on these values. In order to save time of accessing the table again and again with every loop, I am trying to store it in an array and using those arrays I want to compute the values.

Comment: "I just poured myself a glass of water, but the glass isn't big enough so it spilled". What do YOU think you should do in this case? perhaps get some towels to clean up the mess and then find a bigger glass?

Comment: @user2044770 boost your memory ? `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` will increase your memory to 64 MB from the current 32MB. Place that line at the top of your file. If you need more memory adjust the values.

You could also perform calculations in mysql directly.

For example,

> > SELECT SUM(column_1) FROM tbl